# Is it possible 'cd' command using 'which' command?(I want to combine the two commands into one.)

Tags: linux, terminal, command, move, cd

move directories through the **cd** command in Ubuntu, sometimes I don't know the location of a difinte  directory.

When that happens, I find out the location of the directory through which and then use the **cd** command to move it.

[image]

Isn't there a way to combine these two commands into one?

---

### Thanks to the answers, my problem has been solved. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: cd $(dirname $(which xxx))

Comment: Thank you very much.Your answer was very helpful to me. This comment resolved my problem.

Comment: Note that this only works for executable files in PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using subshell. For instance:
`cd $(which something)`